# Remove majority portion of list when exists in other list C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists:

pending = contains ID field and several others

posted = contains only ID field

I want to remove all of the records from pending if the ID field is in the posted list, which works with the following:

```
pending = pending.Where(p => !posted.Any(pp => pp.ID == p.ID)).ToList();
```

however, this does not perform well when for example pending has 600k records and 599,999 of them are in posted

Is there a more efficient way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a more efficient way.

Right now, for each element in list A, you are traversing all of list B in order to try and find it. This is a slow operation.

What you can do is convert list B to a `HashSet` which offers near O(1) direct lookups on the key you select. Then, the traversal of list A will only do a single `Contains()` call for each element to check list B.

```
var listB = new HashSet<int>(posted.Select(i => i.ID));
pending = pending.Where(p => !listB.Contains(p.ID)).ToList();
```

This should speed up your algorithm considerably.

Comment: upvoted but... wouldn't it be more efficient to use [RemoveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-7.0)? `pending.RemoveAll(i => listB.Contains(i.Id))`

Comment: this blew it out of the water.. removed the items seemingly instantly... thank you

Comment: @ɐsɹǝʌǝɔıʌ no, it would be an `O(n*m)` thing in that case, vs an `O(n+m)` thing in my implementation.

Comment: @Rick. You're right. Thanks for clarifying.